# How to add selected Items from a listbox into a table?

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I am still new to VBA and would appreciate some help.
I need to add the selected items from the listbox into a table, but every time I try the displayed table has no values in it.
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub BefehlX_Click()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lstBox As ListBox`

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_Auswertung", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Abfrage4")
    Set lstBox = Me!ListField1       

    For Each varItem In lstBox.ItemsSelected
        strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & lstBox.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
        rs.AddNew

        'what should be placed here?`

        rs.Update
    Next varItem
    Set rs = Nothing

    If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Sie haben keine Queues gewählt!" _
             , vbExclamation, "Nichts zu finden!"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all values in a single string split by ",", then move the `rs.AddNew` to outside the For cycle:

```
For Each varItem In lstBox.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & lstBox.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

'removes first ","
strCriteria = Right(strCriteria , Len(strCriteria ) - 1)

rs.AddNew
rs!NAME_OF_FIELD = strCriteria 
rs.Update
```

If you want to store all values in separate registries (so ID = 1 has one itemselected, and ID = 2 has the next one, and so on) keep the add inside the For cycle:

```
For Each varItem In lstBox.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria =  lstBox.ItemData(varItem)
    rs.AddNew
    rs!NAME_OF_FIELD = strCriteria 
    rs.Update
Next varItem
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this right away and report how it went ;)

Comment: Any doubt about something I wrote, just ask.

Comment: sorry, got some other work in the mean time. 
It seems that the selected Items from the list doesn't get added into the table. This table is displayed in a Subform from where it shows the entries from the want-to-add-from-listbox-table

Comment: actually there are no error messages, so I think the code must be ok. But as I said above, after executing the code no items get added to the table.
Can I use also more than one Field to get items added to? E.g
`For Each varItem In lstBox.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria =  lstBox.ItemData(varItem)
    rs.AddNew
    rs!NAME_OF_FIELD = strCriteria
    rs!NAME_OF_FIELD2 = strCriteria
    rs.Update
Next varItem`

Comment: Sure. It works just like any variable. Make sure your fields are the right data type. String is called "Brief Text" or something on the Access table. So open T_Auswertung, and make sure that your NAME_OF_FIELD has the appropriate data type. You don't get an error because of  DoCmd.SetWarnings (False) I assume, you have to switch it to true (never used it., but that's what it seems to do on the documentation)

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works now. The only thing that isn't working perfectly as I want it is that the data stored in the table is only from the selected field from the listbox and I need to store the whole dataset. But this I can figure on my own ;) Thanks for the help :)

Comment: ListBox.ItemsSelected(linenumber) returns all the selected items. ListBox.ItemData(linenumber) returns all items, by the bound column (in case the listbox has multiple columns). ListBox.Column(linenumb, columnnumb) returns the line/column you select.
So switching lstBox.ItemsSelected for lstBox.ItemData should return the whole listbox collection instead of the selected items.
If you meant you need to store all the columns then don't change the selected part, but instead of ItemData, inside the cycle use a For i = 0 to (NUMB_COLS-1) cycle that iterates all columns in ListBox.Column(varItem, i)